# Where should I ask a question about the best option for migrating my filesystem to the cloud?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Essentially, I want to be able to, for example, use a unix shell in my browser to log into a cloud-based machine.

Comment: A unix shell in a browser seems like such a strange request that I have to ask: You do know about SSH, right?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to Kara, you *might* try [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), where they have a `[webapp-rec]` tag, but I wouldn't hold my breath if I were you. SE communities tend to frown on recommending specific products, services or companies.

Comment: @user152534 - But if phrased in the form of "Which solutions offer features x, y and z" then you're good to go

Comment: Also you can consider asking, "What terminology or search terms do I need to use to find unix shell access providers that have browser based command line interfaces?" to find out what you should be searching for, then search for them and evaluate them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever site you choose, you'll need to assemble a lot more detail if you want a meaningful response.

If you've already got the 'cloud machine' available, and you're just looking for commands/tools to accomplish this in unix, I'm going to go with the [Unix SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).  If you also want to learn about how to set up the 'cloud machine' it's possible that serverfault can help you, but your question will need specifics about goals, limitations, etc.

Sorry - not much to go on, hopefully I'm not being overly simplistic.

Comment: I just want it to be like I'm running a unix shell on my local machine accessing my local files, but I want to do this through a browser accessing a remote machine. I'm not looking for how to set this service up, just a company that offers unix accounts and a browser interface. I assume there are a bunch of options, and I'm curious what the best one is.